# Google PageSpeed Inisghts cannot render page

Tags: seo, google, google-pagespeed

I am getting "The URL was fetched, but nothing was rendered" error in PageSpeed Inisghts, consistently over a few days.

It's a new website.

Every other tool I tried says there's nothing wrong:

- GTMetrix shows PageSpeed 99%, YSlow 90%
- Pingdom gives it 91
- WebPageTest.org gives it AAAAB
- Lighthouse on my PC gives it 85, no errors

Why is PageSpeed unable to render it and how do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Most likely a temporary issue at Google... what does [Google Fetch](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) report? since this is the only report you should be concerned with in regards of rendering the page.

Comment: that works fine. Also this one works OK too https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly. This has been going on for several days now, so it does not look temporary. I wonder if it is related to my location (NZ). It seems to work for GTMetrix, possibly because they're in the US...

Comment: GTMetrix, Web Page Test, Pingdom and others do not render the page, they use loading snapshots which is completely different.Try this third party: https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/fetch-render/

Comment: Can't get to that tool, but google's https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly test works and is able to render the page

Comment: Then there's nothing to worry about. Google insights are poop anyway. If the website is faster than 2 > 1.5 seconds then all is good. Google does not use Insights as a ranking factor and in fact, most of the top ranking websites in the world score extremely badly.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the answer. The problem was in my code. I am calling ipstack.com API to get user's country from IP address. The IP used by PageSpeed does not have a country which I was not handling in my code.

Fixed that and page speed now works fine.

Hopefully this can save someone some time...